# Loops with a condition - Processing

Tags: java, function, loops, processing, nested-loops

Say that a ball is falling down the screen and resets once it hits the border as such:

```
float BallY = 50; // y value of the ball
float BallX = 260; // x value of the ball

void setup()
{
 size(512, 348); //width and height of screen
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(BallX, BallY, 15, 15); //ball that will fall 
  BallY++; //ball's y value increases each frame
  if (BallY > height) //if ball's y value is greater than the screen
{
  BallY = 0; //reset the y value of the ball back to 0
}
}
```

How can I make my "if statement" a "for loop" that creates for example a square on the top left of the screen and creates another one directly beside it each time the ball reaches the end of the screen?

Because my logic was something like:

```
for(float rectangleX=0; (rectangleX+20) <= width; rectangleX+=40){

for(float Bally=0; Bally<height; Bally++){

    rect(rectangleX, 20, 20, 20);
```

But I know this creates a line of rectangles as soon as the program runs and not one by one as the ball falls out of the screen... I am not sure how exactly to put it together. So what is the best method to approach this?

Comment: It's recommended to tag the programming language you're using.

Comment: @alfasin done. thanks

Comment: Why would you even need a loop for that? Creation of the rectangle  is what the `if` block should be doing. To draw just beside of the previous rectangle drawn, you just need to store the position of the previous rectangle (or the reference to the previous rectangle object).

Comment: @Jai yes but loops make it much easier and in lesser lines. I am also trying to learn how to use loops such as "for" and "while"

Comment: Tell me if I'm right. Each time the ball hits the wall, you must draw one more square. For example, if it touched it four times, you draw four squares. Is that it?

Comment: @BrunoL yes you are correct

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is your end goal? Do you have any mocks that show what you're going for?

Comment: @KevinWorkman end goal would be to fill the lines with squares as the ball is crossing the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above you need a counter. Here is a possible solution:

```
float BallY = 50; // y value of the ball
float BallX = 260; // x value of the ball
int counter;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 348); //width and height of screen
  counter = 0;
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(BallX, BallY, 15, 15); //ball that will fall 
  BallY++; //ball's y value increases each frame
  if (BallY > height) //if ball's y value is greater than the screen
  {
    BallY = 0; //reset the y value of the ball back to 0
    counter++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    rect(i * 20, 0, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Peace.

EDIT:
If you want to change the starting x and y position of the rect, you can do in the for loop:

```
rect(100 + i * 20, 100, 20, 20);
```

Comment: This works exactly how i wanted it to so kudos for that, however how do i make it so the first rectangle is not at x-position 20?

Comment: mourad can you please assist with this other small problem it is the same type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521106/using-an-if-statement-within-loops-processing

Answer (score 1):

One thing you're missing is a counter to remember the number of times the ball hit the wall.

Then, with a simple `for` loop from 0 to `counter - 1`, you can draw the rectangles.

You'll need a little formula to compute their left x coordinate but that should not be too difficult.

Comment: What do you mean by left x coordinate?

Comment: The squares have coordinates `(x, y, width, height)`. `x` is the coordinate of the left side of the square.

Comment: I did try to implement what you are saying but I am finding confusing as to how to do a "counter" I dont have that much experience at all with java, what kind of function do we have to use to store values?

Comment: You can simply add a global integer variable `counter` that you increment inside the `if (ballY > height)` instruction block.

Comment: and why are we going from 0 to counter - 1? why the - 1?

Comment: That makes `counter` iterations..If `counter` is `3`, looping through `0, 1, 2` makes 3 iterations. You could also go from 1 to 3 but since Java uses 0-based arrays, counting from 0 becomes more "natural". But both choices work fine.

Comment: So now we should use arrays? your answer was very brief so thanks for the extra info

Comment: No, you shouldn't use arrays. I'm just saying that when you use arrays a lot in Java, you become used to start counting from 0 instead of 1. So, start counting from 0 or 1, as you prefer. :)

Comment: Alright I'll try, still connecting the dots with your hints hoping to get somewhere