# Using an if statement within loops? - Processing

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, processing

Lets say I have to use an if statement within a for loop and the for loop fires at a certain condition and the if statement only fires when the for loop has reached a certain stage.

For example, the condition is a counter that counts up when a certain thing happens such as a ball falling down the screen. circles are drawn one by one everytime the ball crosses the screen. When the circles in the first row have reached the end of the screen, the circles start appearing on the second row below the first one. However the second row isnt working for me, which I have implemented with the if statement.

```
float BallY = 50; // y value of the ball
float BallX = 260; // x value of the ball
float ScoreX = 52;
float ScoreY = 40;
int counter;


void setup()
{
  size(512, 348); //width and height of screen
  counter = 0;
}

void draw()
{
  frameRate(600);
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  ellipse(BallX, BallY, 15, 15); //ball that will fall 
  BallY++; //ball's y value increases each frame
  if (BallY > height) //if ball's y value is greater than the screen
  {
    BallY = 0; //reset the y value of the ball back to 0
    counter++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { 
    ellipse(ScoreX + i * 80, 40, 40, 40); // draw circles in the first row one by one

     if( ScoreX + i * 80 > width) // if the circles cross the width
     {
     i = 0; //reset i to be 0
     ellipse(ScoreX + i * 80, 80, 40, 40); // draw circles in the second row
     }
  }}
```

The if statement is meant to fire only when the balls on the first row are crossing the width, however the whole game just stops instead of firing that row, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Please don't deface your posts-it's completely without meaning now.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? If so, please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First advice: learn the proper Java coding convention, learn how to indent your code, and learn to name your variable.

A slight rewrite on your code should make a readable fix:

```
int scoreStartX = 52;
int scoreStartY = 40;
int scoreBallSize = 40;
// scorePosX/Y means the position the score-ball should be drawn
scorePosX = scoreStartX;  // scoreStartX/Y = starting position of score balls 
scorePosY = scoreStartY;

for (int i = 0; i < score; i++) { 
    ellipse(scorePosX , scorePosY , scoreBallSize , scoreBallSize);

    // increment the positions, and wrap to next col if over screen width
    scorePosX += scoreBallSize ;


   if( scorePosX  > screenWidth) { // next score ball position is beyond the screen
       scorePosX = scoreStartX;
       scorePosY += scoreBallSize;
   }
}
```

---

Further refactoring the code to make use of something like Point to represent coordinate

```
Point scoreStartPos = new Point(52, 40);
int scoreBallSize = 40;
Point scorePos = new Point(scoreStartPos );

for (int i = 0; i < score; i++) { 
   drawCircle(scorePos, scoreBallSize); // a little helper method makes your code easier to read

    // increment the positions, and wrap to next col if over screen width
    scorePos.translate( +scoreBallSize, 0);


   if( scorePos.getX() > screenWidth) { // next score ball position is beyond the screen
       scorePos.setLocation(scoreStartPoint.getX(),
                            scorePos.getY() + scoreBallSize);
   }
}
```

Comment: when you say i < score, what is "score" it hasnt been declared

Comment: it is your original "counter", for which it seems making more sense to call it "score".  And this piece of code is for you to read and understand, not for you to blindly copy

Comment: Actually I would prefer using something like "Point" to represent the coordinate, instead of keeping x and y as separate variables.  Further update the example to give you an idea

Comment: Adrian, this "point" is it a function? I have not seen it and it isn't a function inside the Processing software...

Comment: It is a class. Could be written by you to represent x-y coordinate of a point.  Or you may simply making use Point class in JDK awt etc.  The main point here is extracting proper classes and function will make your code more readable.

Comment: I understand your Code Adrian however, instead of the scoring circles moving onto the next row and filling up the same way as the first row, the first row circles just fall down after they have crossed the width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171753/discussion-between-utsav-and-adrian-shum).

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
i = 0; //reset i to be 0
```

resets the loop index and is therefore likely to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: but if i don't reset i, then the circles will be drawn outside the size of the screen..

Comment: Then you must solve this in some other way (I did not fully understand what you want to achieve). Maybe put a second loop in there with a different loop index?

Comment: But then this "second loop" you talk about must fire only when the first loop has reached a certain stage.. is there a way to connect two loops in such a way?

Comment: Im trying to basically fill the screen with circles, every time the ball crosses the screen, circles appear and they fill the first row, then the second and eventually the whole screen

Comment: "fill the whole screen" sounds like two nested loops. One counting the rows, the other counting the columns.

Comment: yes it does, but I am unsure how to connect two nested loops based on the counter? is there a hint you can provide?

Comment: two counters; `row` and `column`. `row`controls the y-position and `column` controls the x position of the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `i` to `0` every time `ScoreX + i * 80 > width`, right? There are no changes to `ScoreX` or `width`, meaning that the loop will simply count back up to whatever value of `i` makes that condition true, putting you in an infinite loop.

Comment: but i is the one that determines the spacing of the circles.. and if i is not set back to 0, the circles will appear outside the size of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have found the answer to your question.
I give you a possible answer which involves object oriented programming.

Your question is a little bit above the basic stuff.

So a possible answer:

```
float BallY = 50; // y value of the ball
float BallX = 260; // x value of the ball
int counter = 0;

score[] scores; // object oriented programming
int n = 50; // number of objects

void setup() {
  size(512, 348); //width and height of screen
  frameRate(600);

  scores = new score[n]; // object oriented
  float myx = 40;
  float myy = 40;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // here we create our n score objects
    // here n = 50 so 50 objects are created.
    scores[i] = new score(myx, myy);
    // here we increase the x coordinate
    myx += 40;
    // here we check the boundaries and
    // if we go past we reset myx to 40
    // and we go one line down
    if (myx > width) {
      myx = 40;
      myy += 40;
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  fill(0);
  ellipse(BallX, BallY, 15, 15); //ball that will fall 
  BallY++; //ball's y value increases each frame
  if (BallY > height) //if ball's y value is greater than the screen
  {
    BallY = 0; //reset the y value of the ball back to 0
    counter++;
  }

  // we set the color
  fill(255/1, 255/1, 255/2);
  for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    if (counter < n) {
      // we draw the object
      scores[i].score_draw();
    }
  }
}

// OBJECT ORIENTED : THE CLASS
class score {

  float myx, myy;

  score(float x, float y) {
    myx = x;
    myy = y;
  }

  void score_draw() {
    ellipse(myx, myy, 40, 40);
  }
}
```

This works but it gets slower over time. You will have to find out why.

Hope this helps you carry on your learning of processing and programming in general.

PEACE.