# Draw circles permanetly given an if statement - Processing

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, processing

I have an `if` statement which checks for collision as such:

```
if (BallY == y && BallX == x) // check for collision
  {
    x = 80; // reset x to initial
    y = 240; // reset y to initial
    z = 100; //reset z to initial
  }
```

I have a `for` loop inside this `if` statement as such:

```
if (BallY == y && BallX == x) // check for collision
  {
    x = 80; // reset x to initial
    y = 240; // reset y to initial
    z = 100; //reset z to initial
    for (int i=50; i<width; i+=80)
    {
      fill(250,0,0);
      ellipse(i, 50, 70, 70);
    }
  }
```

So the point is to draw a line of circles on the top of the screen once the collision occurs. This code however, only draws them for a split second then they disappear. How would I make them stay given that a collision has occurred?

Comment: If something is reset, then you have code elsewhere that is redrawing your canvas. Please add a [mcve] and mention what library you are using to draw

Comment: Is this in an event-driven GUI? If so, then the solution is not to use a for loop at all.

Comment: Also... Might want to work with this user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521106/using-an-if-statement-within-loops-processing

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so how will i produce circles appearing on the top given that if statement? I dont want to draw circles one by one so I thought loops would be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a `boolean` value that tracks whether the ball has collided. Set it to `true` when you detect a collision, and then check the value to decide what to draw. Here's a simplified example:

```
boolean drawRed = false;

void draw() {

  if (mouseY > height/2) {
    drawRed = true;
  }

  if (drawRed) {
    background(255, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

This code draws a gray background by default, but then turns to red if the mouse goes in the lower half of the window. It stays red even if you move the mouse back to the top part.

This is just a simple example, but the idea is the same: use a variable to track the state of the sketch, set that variable when your condition is met, and check that variable to decide what to draw.

By the way, your collision detection is a little bit suspicious. You probably don't want to check whether the ball is at an exact location. Instead you probably want to check whether the ball overlaps some area. [Here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a guide on collision detection in Processing that might be useful.

If you still can't get it working, please narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting disconnected snippets or your full sketch. Good luck!